# How to get rid of coffee addiction?

Tags: health

I drink 5-8-10 cups of coffee a day prepared on automatic coffee machine.

My problem is that I don't have a stimulating effect from coffee. So I usually feel if I must drink coffee or I feel tired If I don't.

I have tried to get rid of this addiction several times. I can easily stop drinking it for a couple of days (or weeks). First 1-2 days I have a headache and I'm tired; but after that I feel normal. After 2 weeks I tell to myself why not to have 1 coffee, then 2 coffee and very soon I'm again on 5-8 cups a day.

**Update**:
After one year nothing has changed. I'm still on 5-8 cups of strong coffee. I simply like how it smells, I like how it taste.

Comment: Your second paragraph is self-contradictory. If you did not get a stimulating effect, *coffee or no coffee* would not affect how tired you feel...

Comment: 12 step program? But on a more serious note I do relate to this. I normally try to quit when I have time off and am able to sleep more, that's what generally works for me

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'll try to explain: I have to drink coffee otherwise I feel out of energy. Also I think I have caffeine tolerance. It does not matter how much I drink. So when I need a bigger boost let's say I can't get it from coffee.

Comment: I've read that your chances of success may be greater if you wean yourself slowly over a period of weeks. Going from 8-10 cups/day to zero is going to be painful and unsustainable, but going from 10-->8-->6-->4-->2-->zero, week by week is much more manageable and will limit the negative withdrawal effects. The key is to plan it out in advance and *stick to it*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the effects you observe are known as caffeine withdrawal and discussed [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/why-do-i-feel-lousy-low-out-of-energy-after-the-high-coffee-gives/3229#3229).

Coffee addiction is previously discussed [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/will-i-be-addicted-to-caffeine).

However, it is not discussed how to get rid of a coffee addiction. First, you should understand if overcoming this addiction is necessary. I assume, most people who are members of [Coffee SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) are not likely to think that.

[Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Overcome-an-Addiction) is a general link that explains how to get rid of any addiction in three steps:

1. **Decide to quit.** (Think positive future effects, write a commitment to yourself,
   etc.)
2. **Make a plan to quit.** (Set a date, set your environment, overcome the triggers, seek professional help, etc.)
3. **Handle withdrawal.** (Fill your time with new habits, keep clear of triggers, don't find rationalizations to start again, celebrate accomplishments, etc.)

Comment: Steps 2&3 involve getting rid off all your coffee making equipment and coffee, and avoiding coffee shops, the coffee maker at work, etc... and presumably alternate caffeine sources as well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal :) Maybe... I just tried to copy the guidelines of coping with an addiction. Actually, I'm fond of my addiction and no interest in getting rid of coffee.

Comment: I didn't mean you, of course. You (and I) are either at "denial" or "acceptance", depending on one's viewpoint. And as things to be addicted to go, it's pretty benign. But if @user1209304 actually *wants* to quit and has problems with self-control where 1 cup becomes 10, a clean break needs to be made (environment and triggers.)

Answer (score 4):

For the physical addiction, you can reduce the amount of coffee you drink per day. When you get down to half a cup per day, the withdrawal symptoms are minimal.

Even quitting cold turkey can be done. I've done it, and I was a zombie with headache for two days, and then I was OK.

The bigger problem is the psychological addiction. You have to be really motivated to overcome it.

While trying to get pregnant and through entire pregnancy with my daughter I didn't have even a sip of coffee - but after I stopped breastfeeding her, I started drinking coffee again.

I just love the smell of coffee, the joy of drinking it, ... I can quit any time. I just don't want to.

UPDATE:
Yes, I think it's possible to overcome psychological addiction with decaf.

Another thing: If you need caffeine to help you function, it's not just about getting rid of addiction, but also developing a couple habits that will reduce the need for caffeine:

1. exercise regularly
2. drink enough water
3. maintain a good sleep hygiene:

   - get 8 hour of sleep every night (or the amount you need, if you determine you need more or less)
   - go to bet at the same time every night
   - wake up at the same time every morning

Comment: Can you handle the psychological addiction by switching to decaf or to herbal tea like Roastaroma?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a little less coffee over the course of a few weeks. Start out with your normal amount, and slowly start dropping it.

Answer (score 1):

i came across this interesting article on [getting rid of coffee addiction](http://naturallybeautiful.life/how-to-get-rid-of-coffee-addiction/)

> Change your habits. If you realize that you are addicted to coffee and
> you do not like this, well try to change your habits....
>
> Try to substitute. I find it very interesting to note that oftentimes
> people have more of a psychological dependency or tradition rather
> than need for coffee. ...

Comment: Dear Sergey, welcome to [Coffee SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/). By tradition, instead of repeating the same answer under similar questions, we post links of similar answers.